# How to configure dburl of different server in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have a config.json file where I have kept the DB URL of all the servers i.e. "localhost, dev". But the issue is how to configure the DB URL dynamically in server.js. If I have opened localhost it should take localhost DB URL and if dev then it should take dev DB URL.

config.json file

```
{
  localhost:{
     "dburl":mongodb://localhost:5009/abc",
     "port": "1000",
  },

  dev:{
     "dburl":mongodb://12.34.456.789:5009/def",
     "port": "2000",
  }
}
```

server.js

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let session = require('express-session');
let config = require('./config/config.json');
let MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
let http = require("http")
let app = express();


let mongoDB = config.localhost.dburl;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(db => {
    console.log('MONGO CONNECTED');
});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

const port = config.localhost.port;

http.createServer(app).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server listening to ${port}`);
});
```

This is only for localhost, my dev server.js is different. I have to change manually in both the server.js file(localhost and dev).
Anyone any idea how to configure it automatically so that whichever server i am running it should detect automatically and take its corresponding dburl and port. Or any other way to do it to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You could start your server with `NODE_ENV` environment variable set to your current env. For example:

for localhost:

```
$ NODE_ENV=localhost node index.js
```

for dev:

```
$ NODE_ENV=dev node index.js
```

and then in your `server.js` file, you could use it:

```
let mongoDB = config[process.env.NODE_ENV].dburl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `config` package on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

By setting the `NODE_ENV` env variable before starting your server, the `config` package will be able to read the related config file automatically.